# Custom widget js doesn't recognize template from qweb

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I try to test custom widget from [js reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#widgets) and I get error in debugger:

> Error: QWeb2: Template 'some.template' not found

qweb.xml was properly set in manifest, because when I extend ListController and use another template, it works correctly.

Here is template definition, which I use in qweb.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>
    <div t-name="some.template">
        <span class="val"><t t-esc="widget.count"/></span>
        <button>Increment</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

I tried to change `<template>` -> `<templates>`, totally removed tag "template" but still get the same error message.

JS:

```
odoo.define('working.test', function (require) {
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var Counter = Widget.extend({
    template: 'some.template',
    events: {
        'click button': '_onClick',
    },
    init: function (parent, value) {
        this._super(parent);
        this.count = value;
    },
    _onClick: function () {
        this.count++;
        this.$('.val').text(this.count);
    },
});

// Create the instance
var counter = new Counter(this, 4);
// Render and insert into DOM
counter.appendTo(".o_nocontent_help");

})
```

Manifest:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "testwidget",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base'],
    'qweb': ['static/qweb.xml'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/web_asset.xml',
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}
```

Any idea how I need to modify this template to make the widget working correctly and in which table in db odoo stores these templates?

Comment: Could you put the js code and the manifest file ?

Comment: sure, already updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into this same issue and needed to put my QWeb code into `static/src/xml/base.xml` in order for Odoo to recognize it.

You can check to see if Odoo is loading the QWeb by going to this URL on your Odoo instance:

```
<odoo_instance>/web/webclient/qweb?mods=<my_module_name>
```

Such as:

```
localhost:8069/web/webclient/qweb?mods=test
```

For comparison, you can see a successful output by using `mods=web` to load the QWeb assets for the `web` module.

Comment: When I open localhost:8069/web/webclient/qweb?mods=test I can see new qweb teamplate but still when loads js the log in console is: QWeb2: Template 'some' not found. Any idea why even if template is already visible and DB is restarted it's still not recognizable?

Comment: Your template should be declared by `t` elements, not `div` elements. Your questions shows `<div t-name="some.template">` instead of `<t t-name="some.template">`.

Comment: Another thing: if the error says `Template "some" not found` then I think you might be referencing `some` instead of `some.template` in your code. Normally, I would expect the error message to say `Template "some.template" not found`

Comment: I removed div and still the same error in console.log. Regarding 'some' I've just locally renamed a lot of things with a hope that it will refresh data. I added all changes in this rep: https://bitbucket.org/jarvee/test/src/master/

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing

```
'qweb': ['static/qweb.xml'],
```

to

```
'qweb': ['static/*.xml'],
```

It happens with me sometimes, by specifying static xml file name, it does not render that template. But by just loading all .xml files by using *, templates are loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it according to your advise but still I'm getting the same error message. The whole code you can check on this repository: https://bitbucket.org/jarvee/test/src/master/

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I used as workaround Widget.xmlDependencies:

```
 xmlDependencies: ['/test/static/qweb.xml']
```

but the main reason I think was cache in PyCharm which I didn't invalidate.

Answer (score 1):

After having done some code reading, IMO, I realized the official documentation might not have pointed out clearly how to use templates in frontend.

To summarize my understanding:

The 'qweb' field in manifest is mainly designed for *webclient* (i.e. the *backoffice*), not the website. When entering webclient, a request to /web/webclient/qweb is made to retrieve all the templates of installed modules.

In order to use templates in *website* (i.e. *frontend*), synchronous and asynchronous ways both exist.

- Synchronous way: Use *qweb.add_template*.  When parameter is template content itself or a DOM node, template is loaded in a synchronous way. (While param is a URL, then it fires up an ajax request to server to fetch content.)

  qweb.add_template is mentioned in https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/qweb.html
- Asynchronous way:

  1. Use *ajax.loadXML* which you can use anywhere you want to start loading template from a URL.
  2. Use *xmlDependencies* which you specify in widget definition. And if you dig into the code in widget.js, you can see ajax.loadXML is being used in *willStart*.

There are discussions regarding *qweb.add_template* vs *ajax.loadXML*
See https://github.com/OCA/pylint-odoo/issues/186 and  https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/20821

FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may need to make sure that the js definition refers to the module name correctly

```js
odoo.define('MODULE TECHNICAL NAME SHOULD BE HERE.test', function (require) {});
```

you should also register your js function with something like:

```js
core.action_registry.add("module_name.name", Widget_Extend);
```

for more info https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#registries

Comment: Thanks, I changed it according to your advise but still I'm getting the same error message. The whole code you can check on this repository: bitbucket.org/jarvee/test/src/master

Comment: @edward may i know whether you have resolved the issue?  i have a similar situation here and am confused by the documentation.

Comment: @ycl yes, I used as a workaround xmlDependencies in that case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with "hr_org_chart" template idk why everything works fine in another computer but in mine it returned this problem, I solved it by installing this module [hr-org-chart](https://odoo-community.org/shop/hr-org-chart-overview-5399?category=11#attr=8242)